# Wrong time separator for a C# DateTime on Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, azure, datetime-format, azure-web-app-service

if I use this line of code on an azure website

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("it-IT"))
```

the page prints

```
13/02/2014 12.08.45
```

but the time separator is wrong, should be

```
13/02/2014 12:08:45
```

Am I doing something wrong or is an azure bug?

**EDIT**

I run the test program Jon Skeet suggest me, and these are the results

```
PS D:\desktop> .\test
13/02/2014 12:50:32
Runtime: 2.0.50727.5472
PS D:\desktop> .\test
13/02/2014 12:50:47
Runtime: 4.0.30319.18408
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's a Windows 8 (Server 2012) issue. In Windows 8 the it-IT culture was updated to use `.` instead of `:` as it used to in Windows 7. In 8.1 it was updated again to `:` after some feedback from customers.

You can see that in Control Panel if you have a Windows 7 or 8.1 machine vs a Windows 8 machine. [Culture data shouldn't be considered stable (except for Invariant)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2005/04/05/405694.aspx)

Azure Websites are currently using Windows 8 (Server 2012) VMs

#### Windows 7 and 8.1

[image: Windows 7 and 8.1 it-IT culture]

#### Windows 8

[image]

for a workaround please check `Shawn Steele` reply here
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf5fa2c1-b6ce-4e4e-b9dd-17191afca4be/web-services-culture?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview&prof=required

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's to do with the version of the CLR being used. On the CLR prior to v4, the culture information being used *did* have the time separator as `.`. On CLR v4+, it's `:`. I don't know why... presumably CLR v4+ is reading the regional information from a different (newer?) location. (I suspect it's down to the CLR version being used, basically.)

Anyway, I suspect if you can force your Azure service to use .NET 4, it will be okay. I *suspect* you'll find it's using .NET 3.5 at the moment.

As an example, take this code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(culture));
        Console.WriteLine("Runtime: {0}", Environment.Version);
    }
}
```

Compile it with the C# 2 compiler:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc Test.cs
```

And create a Test.exe.config file:

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment out one of those `supportedRuntime` elements at a time to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the quickly reply!
In my azure panel, on my website, I was already using .NET FRAMEWORK VERSION V 4.5, but I've added the line in my web.config and still nothing <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/></startup>.

Comment: @Sig.Tolleranza: What do you mean?

Comment: @Sig.Tolleranza: Can you log the CLR version, as per my edit? Perhaps Azure is using an old version of some regional settings? That would seem odd...

Comment: Yeah, sure; I've removed the web.config line and, on azure, i've get this Runtime: 4.0.30319.19408

Comment: @Sig.Tolleranza: Right. In that case, I don't understand :(

Comment: Is it possibile this is an Azure Bug? I mean the CLR version used by azure... How can I report this?

Comment: @Sig.Tolleranza: No, it's fine that it's using that version of the CLR - it's just odd that it's still using `.`. I don't know the best way of reporting Azure bugs, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a bug.

Because `it-IT` culture's [`TimeSeperator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `.` not `:`

```
CultureInfo c = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-IT");
Console.WriteLine(c.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator); //Prints .
```

**EDIT**: Wait a second.. There is something going tricky here..

I think *[Jon is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21752701/447156)* because on my machine I run this with .NET 3.5 and that's why it prints `.` instead of `:`

If you can force your Azure service to use .NET 4+ you get `:` instead of `.`

Comment: Not on my machine it doesn't :)